# git - find divergences of a branch

Tags: git

I have a branch **A** that diverged into other branches. I also have more branches that didn't diverge from that **A** branch. How can I find which branches diverged from A?

For example:

```
-------------------------------- Master
 \  \
  \   -------------------------- A
   \         \
    \          ----------------- B
     \           \
      \            ------------- C
       \
        \
          ---------------------- D
                \
                  -------------- E
```

I want the output to be B and C.

Comment: The concept of branch that diverged from another branch is a bit fuzzy in git. This is because branches are simply pointers to one commit and the repo history is not always a tree.

Comment: For example, look at [this graph](http://pastebin.com/qc4Umc2g) and tell me which branches "diverge" from A

Comment: This being said, you could attempt to find the branches whose [common ancestor](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html) with branch A is ahead of master. However, after branch A and its descendent are merged back into master, this would no longer work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git branch --contains` should provide what you want.

The `--contains` option shows us all branches that contain a specific commit-ish. The commit we want is the first one on `A` after it branched from `master`. It'd be easier to get the `merge-base` of `A` and `master`, but that will also be contained by `master` and anything branching from `master` after `A` does.

We can find the first commit SHA on `A` with:

```
git log --format=format:%h master..A | tail -1
```

`%h` gives us the short commit SHA, so we don't have to slice up the default output afterwards. `tail` picks off the earliest commit on `A`, or you could also pass `log` the `--reverse` option and use `head`. If your branch is a million commits long, that will let processes [die sooner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29964/are-linux-utilities-smart-when-running-piped-commands), but at that point you've probably got other concerns.

Then, we use `A`'a first SHA in `branch --contains`:

```
git branch --contains $(git log --format=format:%h master..A | tail -1) --no-merged A
```

The `--no-merged A` option ignores branch `A` itself, which clearly contains the commit we picked.

If you've currently checked out one of the branches that diverged from `A`, git will indicate that with a `*` like it does when you just run `git branch`. I can't find a way to strip that in pure Git, but you can use any number of unix commands to remove it from the output.

Comment: almost the right answer - since contains needs <commit> and not name of branch. correct it to have git log master..A --oneline | tail -1    and then I'll mark your answer as right. BTW I can live without the --no--merged issue

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that `--contains` will take a commit-ish. Using a branch there worked just fine for me (v2.2.1).

Comment: I tried this with the name of the branch and the only result I got was the branch itself. And it is logical if you look in my example that only A contained in A.

Comment: Aaah, I see my mistake. I was reading your diagram to have `A` as a commit before `B` branched, not `A` as the `HEAD` of that branch, which continued after `B` split off. I've updated your diagram so no one else will think that, and updated the answer with your `tail` version. Teamwork!